# How to unban myself from my own Minecraft PE Server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I went on the leet app and re-entered my name as the admin and it still did not work. First, it said I was kicked by the admin and then it said I was banned. I can't contact the admin because I am the admin.

What do I do to unban myself so I can play on my own server?

Comment: check player.txt or banned ips.txt  for your name or ip and if so remove it

Comment: I don't know exactly how realms work as I only use dedicated servers, but if you have the server files, you should be able to use a console to unban yourself. You can also contact customer support at support@leet.cc

Comment: Thank you John Smith, I am going to try that. P.S I'm on PE

Answer (score 2):

If you can access the server files, you can create a new server and copy the old worlds directory into the new worlds directory. When I tried to go to leet [dot] cc, Norton warned me that it was a bad site. Leet might be doing this. This is just a possible idea, I have no experience with Leet except for that Norton pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change your username, because if it is not an IP ban, changing your username will be a quick, and easy fix. If it was someone on your server, who banned you you should still have OP permissions. I have done this when I had a friend, get banned from a person with the same permissions, he changed his username, and had his permissions as well as being able, to get onto the server.